# Angular 4 tslint and codelyser

Tags: angular

I want to understand the practical implication of tslint and codelyser in Angular 4. How would these are used in the real scenario and how would i customise the rules defined in tslint.

Answer (score 1):

> TSLint is an extensible static analysis tool that checks TypeScript
>   code for readability, maintainability, and functionality errors.

Basically it will help you write clean and cool code. See setup and CLI usage [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/).

As a simple example, when you are using [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) to generate an application, you will have `tsconfig.json` for setting up how are you using Typescript, and you are getting a `tslint.json` file where you can set rules usage and definitions. You can read about that file [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/tslint-json/).

And about the core rules [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/).

You can run the analysis bu typing `lint` or `ng lint` in your project's folder in command line.
*(This is configured in the generated `package.json` file by Angular CLI, or you can copy that setting over in your project if not created with Angular CLI)*